# Accessing DynamicJsonArray in F#

Tags: .net, f#, dynamicobject

I'm looking into F# for personal 'fun' reasons and to explore thinking in a functional way.
I'm trying to duplicate the functionality of this other code snippet I wrote this morning: [here](https://github.com/fuginator/jogos/blob/master/c%23/jogos/Program.cs).

I've written this code below, however it seems I can't really access items in my `for ... in` statement.

```
open System
open System.Net
open System.Web.Helpers

let data = Json.Decode((new WebClient()).DownloadString("http://sw.cs.wwu.edu/~fugiera/matches"))

let myList = [for x : DynamicJsonArray in downcast data do if x?status != "complete" then yield x?home_team.goals ]

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

I'm really just trying to wrap my head around everything right now, and could use a pointer or two!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your `for` loop is casting in the wrong place. You want to cast `data` to `DynamicJsonArray`, not `x`.  You also need to cast `x` to `DynamicJsonObject`.

```
let myList = [
    for x in (data :?> DynamicJsonArray) do
        let x = x :?> DynamicJsonObject
        ...
```

F# doesn't have built-in support for dynamic objects like this the way C# does, so you can't use a standard operator like `?` to get at the properties of your object.

I spent about 20 seconds attempting to figure out how one *does* extract dynamic properties using normal APIs, but got bored.

Luckily, F# has a feature called Type Providers which in some ways are like dynamic objects, but on super steroids.  They would work perfectly here.

Add a reference to the NuGet package [`FSharp.Data`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data) and try this code on for size:

```
open FSharp.Data

type WorldCup = JsonProvider<"http://worldcup.sfg.io/matches">

for game in WorldCup.GetSamples() do
    match (game.Status, game.HomeTeam.Record, game.AwayTeam.Record) with
    | ("completed", Some(ht), Some(at)) ->
        printfn "%s %d vs %s %d" ht.Country ht.Goals at.Country at.Goals
    | _ -> ()
```

If you just want working code, there ya go.  For some more details, read on.

Some things to notice, comparing to your linked C# code:

- You get intellisense on the JSON objects, showing you the available properties (don't get that in C#)
- If you typo a property name, or make an assumption about a property always being available when it isn't, your code won't build.  This prevents all kinds of runtime errors that can happen in C#.

In particular, notice that in the raw JSON, `game.HomeTeam` is not always present (i.e. for not-yet-played games this is not populated).  Your C# accesses `game.home_team.country, game.home_team.goals` anyways, because you are filtering on `status`.  That works ok for now, but in general it's risky since that could blow up at runtime.

In F#, the JSON type provider notices that `HomeTeam` and `AwayTeam` are not always present, so it exposes them as [`option` types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx).  You are *required by the type system* to consider what to do when those values are missing.  That's a good thing!

So you see that the code checks for 3 things: 1. `status = "completed"` 2. `HomeTeam` is defined (is `Some(homeTeam)`, not `None`) 3. `AwayTeam` is defined. If so, we print the details.  If not, skip it.

Comment: This is an awesome response!  Thanks for clearing up not only how to solve my problem, but also taking the time to explain the deeper concepts to me.  F# looks like an interesting language that I intend on spending more time with.  Thanks again!